# Remove model validation on form submit

Tags: validation, cakephp

I have a form in cakephp 2.5.
If a save button is clicked, the record is updated with all validation applicable

If a spam button is clicked the form is submitted with a flag to mark the record as deleted. 
If in this case the email address is not a valid one, the form will not submit because the validation set from the model is not passed. Is there any way to remove the validation on the fly?

I've looked into using `$this->validator()->remove('email');` but this is no use as the validation is already set before the view is rendered.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use validation rules on your controller instead?

This way, you can leave the rules on the model, but only use them a condition is fullfiled

```
if ($this->ModelName->validates()) {
    // it validated logic
} else {
    // didn't validate logic
    $errors = $this->ModelName->validationErrors;
}
```

Or you can disable validation by simply

```
if ($this->ModelName->saveAll(
    $this->request->data, array('validate' => false)
)) {
    // saving without validation
}
```

Comment: The form won't submit to allow the save method to be called as it doesn't pass validation. The validation is applied to the view before it gets rendered. I need to disable it on the fly depending on a button press.

Comment: I don't know if it works for validation too, but have you tried `$this->Form->unlock` for this input? I know it prevents the render to encrypt the field and allows javascript to interact with it, maybe it overcome validation. In this case, you should really let your controller extend validation from your model and in this field put all the validation logic into the controller, not in the view